# PyArg_ParseTuple causing segmentation fault

Tags: python, c, argument-passing, python-c-extension

I'm trying to call a c function from my extension and have narrowed the problem down to this test case.

```
#import "Python.h"

...

// Called from python with test_method(0, 0, 'TEST')
static PyObject*
test_method(PyObject *args)
{
    int ok, x, y, size;
    const char *s;

    // this causes Segmentation fault
    //ok = PyArg_ParseTuple(args, "iis#", &x, &y, &s, &size); 

    // also segfaults
    //if(ok) PyErr_SetString(PyExc_SystemError, 'Exception');

    // this does not cause segfault but fills the variables with garbage   
    ok = PyArg_ParseTuple(&args, "iis#", &x, &y, &s, &size);

    // Example: >test_method 0, 37567920, (garbage)
    printf(">test_method %d, %d, %s\n", x, y, s);

    /* Success */
    Py_RETURN_NONE;
}

static PyMethodDef testMethods[] =
{
     {"test_method", test_method, METH_VARARGS,
             "test_method"},
     ...

     {NULL, NULL, 0, NULL}
};
```

Any ideas what I might be doing wrong. (Python version 2.6.4).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmmm. I think the signature of your method should be this:

```
static PyObject* test_method(PyObject* self, PyObject* args)
```

If you are invoking your `test_method` as a bound method (i.e. a method of some object instance), `self` will be the object itself. If `test_method` is a module function, `self` is the pointer passed to `Py_InitModule4()` when you initialized the module (or NULL if you used `Py_InitModule()`). The thing is that Python makes no distinctions between bound instance methods and ordinary functions at the code level, that's why you have to pass `self` even if you are implementing a plain function.

See [this page](http://docs.python.org/c-api/structures.html#METH_VARARGS) for more details.

Comment: That was it, out of curiosity, what is *self referring to ? The module ?

Comment: I've extended my response to answer that.